# clearInterval isn't working in class function javascript

Tags: javascript, class, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to stop the interval but for some reason it doesn't stop when I call the clearInterval() method.
When I click on the button the function callPauseTimer gets executed correctly as my two logs are shown in the console, so it must be something linked to the interval itself.
I'm working with classes for the first time so I'm probably missing something, and I've been searching about the topic for two hours without results...

```
let endTimer = "0";
const app = document.querySelector(".app");

//! CLASS
class Timer {
  constructor(endTimer) {
    this.endTimer = endTimer;
  }

  startTimer() {
    if (this.endTimer === "0") {
      this.endTimer = new Date().getTime() + 1500000;
    }
    this.displayTime();
  }

  displayTime() {
    let now = new Date().getTime();
    let remainingTime = this.endTimer - now;
    let minutes = Math.floor(remainingTime / 1000 / 60);
    let seconds = Math.floor((remainingTime / 1000) % 60);
    if (seconds < 10) {
      seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    timer.innerHTML = `<h1>${minutes}:${seconds}</h1>`;
    start.innerHTML = `
        STOP
        <i class="fas fa-pause"></i>
    `;
    this.interval = setInterval(this.displayTime.bind(newTimer), 1000);
  }

  callPauseTimer() {
    console.log(this.interval);
    console.log("test");
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}

let newTimer = new Timer(endTimer);

//! EVENT LISTENERS

app.addEventListener("click", callEvent);

//! FUNCTIONS

function callEvent(e) {
  let event = e.target.innerText;
  console.log(event);
  if (event === "START") {
    newTimer.startTimer();
  } else if (event === "STOP") {
    newTimer.callPauseTimer();
  }
}
```

EDIT:
This is the solution, you just need to not repeat the setInterval each time the displayTime is called:

```
let endTimer = "0";
let reload = false;
const app = document.querySelector(".app");

//! CLASS
class Timer {
  constructor(endTimer, reload) {
    this.endTimer = endTimer;
    this.reload = reload;
  }

  startTimer() {
    if (this.endTimer === "0") {
      this.endTimer = new Date().getTime() + 1500000;
    }
    this.reload = true;
    this.displayTime();
  }

  displayTime() {
    let now = new Date().getTime();
    let remainingTime = this.endTimer - now;
    let minutes = Math.floor(remainingTime / 1000 / 60);
    let seconds = Math.floor((remainingTime / 1000) % 60);
    if (seconds < 10) {
      seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    timer.innerHTML = `<h1>${minutes}:${seconds}</h1>`;
    start.innerHTML = `
        STOP
    `;
    this.remainingTime = remainingTime;
    if (this.reload === true) {
      this.startInterval();
    }
    this.reload = false;
  }

  startInterval() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.displayTime(), 1000);
  }

  clearInterval() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  callPauseTimer() {
    this.clearInterval();
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use `bind(this)` so that the class isn't dependent on the name of the variable.

Comment: ^^ Or just `this.interval = setInterval(() => this.displayTime(), 1000);`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Your `setInterval()`, which is called from `displayTime()`, is calling `displayTime()`. Every interval, it will schedule another interval. Those stack. (And overwrite the previously set `this.interval`.)

Comment: In `displayTime`, what is `start`? What is `timer`?

Comment: Ah, @Ivar, you've put your finger on it. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody, it was indeed a problem with the setInterval which was created each time, I'll leave the correct code on the original post in case anybody who looks for something like this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder for the `start` and `timer` part, they are the display on the actual page through DOM, I omitted the variable declaration from the original post so that it was shorter

Comment: @GiovanniBeccaro - Best not to do that (or to at least say what they are). :-)